# New line JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Location Test </title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> Location </h1>
      <label id = "Address"> </label>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="Log Out" id="LogOut">
  <script>
    const logoutButton = document.getElementById("LogOut");

function getLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(Position) {
            var currentdate = new Date();
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/" +
                (currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
                currentdate.getFullYear() + ". " +
                currentdate.getHours() + ":" +
                currentdate.getMinutes() + "." +
                currentdate.getSeconds() + ". ";
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + "Latitude: " + Position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Longitude: " + Position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Accuracy: " + Position.coords.accuracy;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Heading towards direction: " + Position.coords.heading;
            document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Speed: " + Position.coords.speed;
            var api_key = '206170168bcf4fdf905d85a34f7b3d79';
            var latitude = Position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = Position.coords.longitude;
            var api_url = 'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json'
            var request_url = api_url +
                '?' +
                'key=' + api_key +
                '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(latitude + ',' + longitude) +
                '&pretty=1' +
                '&no_annotations=1';
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', request_url, true);
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    // Success!
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("Address").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Address").textContent + " Address: " + data.results[0].formatted; // print the location

                } else if (request.status <= 500) {
                    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

                    console.log("unable to geocode! Response code: " + request.status);
                    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    console.log('error msg: ' + data.status.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("server error");
                }
            };
            request.onerror = function() {
                console.log("unable to connect to server");
            };
            request.send(); // make the request
        },
        function(PositionError) {
            document.getElementById("Latitude").innerHTML = "Could not get latitude";
            document.getElementById("Longitude").innerHTML = "Could not get longitude";
        })
}
getLocation();
setInterval(getLocation, 1000 * 60 * 5)
logoutButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "login.html";
    }) 
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

So basically, what I want to do is create a new line at the end of the function. So each time I use setInterval, it creates a new line in the label. But I'm not sure how to. That way, every time it updates the location after 5 minutes, it prints it on a new line.
You can ignore the rest of what I say, I'm getting the error that my post is mostly code.

Answer (score 4):

Just write a `<br>` tag. So change

```
+ " Address: "
```

to:

```
+ "<br> Address: "
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

As **trincot** stated, the inclusion of the `<br>` ([line break](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_br.asp)) tag is the way to go as we want to create new lines directly in the **address label**. However, a code change is required because our newly appended line breaks will get rewritten when we re-call function `getLocation()`.

Appended line breaks will vanish if we reinitialise our label's **innerHTML** with its previous **textContent** because **textContent** selects the message from the target and ignores nested HTML contents.

Thus, the best solution is to formulate the **location** before its inclusion to the **address label**.

```
// Get local date and time.
var currentdate = new Date();
var cd_date = currentdate.toLocaleDateString("en-UK");
var cd_time = currentdate.toLocaleTimeString("en-UK");

// Formulate location string.
var location = `

    Last Sync: ${cd_date} - ${cd_time},
    Latitude: ${Position.coords.latitude},
    Longitude: ${Position.coords.longitude},
    Accuracy: ${Position.coords.accuracy},
    Heading towards direction: ${Position.coords.heading},
    Speed: ${Position.coords.speed},

`.replace(/\s{2}/g, '').trim(); // Remove additional spaces.
```

...

```
if (request.status === 200) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    location += ` Address: "${data.results[0].formatted}".`;
                        
    // print the location
    var elm_address = document.getElementById("Address");
    elm_address.innerHTML += (elm_address.innerHTML.trim().length > 0) ? `<br>${location}` : location;    
}
```

We want to include line breaks when we append additional **location** to the **address label**, so I decided to have a conditional statement before appending stage.

> `elm_address.innerHTML +=` will append the **location** after
> following condition `(elm_address.innerHTML.trim().length > 0)`.

The condition checks if **address label** is empty.

```
? `<br>${location}` : location;
```

When the condition's result is negative, **location** is appended without a line break. Otherwise, a line break is included.